# Skip duplicate rows via primary key per server side trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working with a not so great export function to mysql from GLS and I don't get access to the query it uses, so I could just do INSERT IGNORE instead.

The way this thing is able to sync makes it impossible to avoid duplicates but the syncing breaks on the first error.

So I need a way to skip any duplicates so the tool continues (sigh).

I threw a bone to ChatGPT and it came up with this, but after trying to fix the syntax for a while I'm convinced it's just crap:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER verhindere_duplikate
BEFORE INSERT ON deine_tabelle
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE dup_count INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO dup_count FROM deine_tabelle WHERE primary_key = NEW.primary_key;
    IF dup_count > 0 THEN            
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there a way to solve this issue server side?

Comment: Explain your task more detailed. If I understood correctly, there exists a table with some uniqueness constraint (primary key), and there exists some software which performs an insertion into this table specifying the value for unique column. If the value specified already exists then the query fails which result in the application fail. In this case the trigger cannot help you, and you must search for some another solution. Tell more about your system.

Answer (score 0):

As Akina suggested, more details pertaining to your task are required. So at this stage, this is what I can come up with.

By ***The way this thing is able to sync makes it impossible to avoid duplicates but the syncing breaks on the first error*** ,I suppose you are using an app for data replication from your GLS dataset to MySQL. And it's unlikely the source has a uniqueness constraint mechanism, which is why duplicate PK values exist. In this case, if duplicate values are unavoidable, I would recommend the following three workarounds.

**Method 1**: 
Adjust the duplicate values to make them unique again when they propagate,such as appending them with an ID like '-DP01' if the PK is of string type. A trigger is required to carry out the job. Honestly speaking, this is not really a good choice.

**Method 2**: 
Make the PK composite if **you are certain** the current PK column + another column can make a unique pair. Apart from table structure, data values remain intact. And no trigger is necessary in this case.

**Method 3**: 
Remove the PK attribute and add a new column to remark the uniqueness. e.g a dup_id column of integer type with value 0 indicating value is unique and higher ones marking the ?th duplicate instance. Or we can mix this and **method 2** by making a composite PK out of current PK and dup_id column. Like in method 1, a trigger is involved in the process.

Depending on how you would like the data to populate in the DB, if least data change is desired, I would try method 2 if it's eligible.

Comment: It's the GLS app itself that only allows automated export based on relative number of days, as in last 5 for example.

Because I cannot predict when the export will be fired up, the same days will inevitably be synced causing either duplicates (no primary key) or errors and a halt.

Comment: Ok, my dirty solution is now no primary key, a table thats complete chaos to just get filled up by that awful query and a trigger on that table inserting everything into another table with a primary key:

BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO Nicko
    SELECT * FROM ShipIT
    WHERE TrackID = trackID;
END

That has to be a performance nightmare in the long run, but it works.

Comment: Is it possible to manage how or what the app replicates ? If it's not viable to do so, then dupe rows are inevitable at the time of replication. It would be like the app is routinely executing the same query `insert tb select * from gls where datediff(now(),the_date)<5`. Although we can avoid dupe errors by simply dropping PK, the dupe rows would be a pain.

Comment: And since you cannot predict the interval between each export, we can not set a perfectly timed event scheduler to remove dupe rows RIGHT AFTER the data sync finishes. As a result, if we were using event scheduler, we would have to resort to things like `select distinct` due to the untimely cleanup of dupe rows. But at the minimum, dupe rows wouldn't pile up.

Comment: Please try to stay clear of using a trigger on a transition table doing `INSERT IGNORE INTO Nicko SELECT * FROM ShipIT WHERE TrackID = trackID;` , it would be bad on performance >_< But if you insist, at the very least set an event scheduler at regular interval to clean the transition table, as no rows are required to fill the vacancy.